# My Lua embedding have no _G table, but I can set global variable with _G table

Tags: lua, global-variables, lua-table

I embedded Lua into my app, but not loaded standard library. I checked there is no `_G` table, but I could set some global variables. How is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is still a table of globals inside Lua. It's just not visible as a variable.

If you load the `package` library then the table of globals is accessible in Lua via `package.loaded._G`.